# How to configure folders with 'Child Theme'?

Tags: child-theme, directory

I created a 'Child Theme' for customize my Template but I don't know how to subscribe some files that found in folders of the theme. I tried to do like this:

Original files: theme/css/file.css
I would like: child-theme/css/file.css

Is it possible do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override existing parent's css file, create the exact same file with exact same path and it will override it.

Example: *parentTheme/css/awesome_style.css*

To overwrite it you should create: *parentTheme-child/css/awesome_style.css*

More info: [Child Themes -> Template Files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files)

You could also add rules to the existing css, you can read more about it in [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Or if you want to get stylesheet directory URI, you can use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.